# Proving :$\arctan(1)+\arctan(2)+ \arctan(3)=\pi$

Tags: trigonometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does $\tan^{-1}(1)+\tan^{-1}(2)+\tan^{-1}(3)=\pi$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197393/why-does-tan-11-tan-12-tan-13-pi)

How to prove $$\arctan(1)+\arctan(2)+ \arctan(3)=\pi$$

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197393/why-does-tan-11-tan-12-tan-13-pi

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As $$\tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B},$$
$$\tan (A+B+C)=\frac{\tan(A+B)+\tan C}{1-\tan(A+B)\tan C}=\frac{\frac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B}+\tan C}{1-\tan C\left(\frac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B}\right)}=\frac{\tan A+\tan B+\tan C-\tan A\tan B\tan C}{1-\tan A\tan B-\tan B\tan C-\tan C\tan A}$$

So, $$A+B+C=\arctan\left(\frac{\tan A+\tan B+\tan C-\tan A\tan B\tan C}{1-\tan A\tan B-\tan B\tan C-\tan C\tan A}\right)+m\pi$$ where $m$ is any integer.

Putting $\tan A=1, \tan B=2,\tan C=3$,

So, $$\arctan 1+m_1\pi+\arctan 2y+m_2\pi+\arctan 3+m_3\pi=\arctan 0+m\pi$$  where $m_i$ are integers.

The general value of 
$\arctan 1+\arctan 2+\arctan 3=\arctan 0+(m-m_1-m_2-m_3)\pi$
$=(n+m-m_1-m_2-m_3)\pi=r\pi$ where $n$ is any integer, hence $r=n+m-m_1-m_2-m_3$ is.

As the special value of each of the inverse trigonometric function lies in $\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)$ so their sum will lie in $(0,\frac{3\pi}2).$
Hence,  the special value being $0\cdot\pi=0$

Comment: I'm not convinced this will make it more clear for the OP. I suggest adding that what you did is find $\tan(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)$.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė, added the proof

Comment: The problem is, $\tan(x) = y$ doesn't mean $\arctan(y) = x$, unless you're using a multivalued version of arctan.  For the standard arctan, which has $-\pi/2 < \arctan(t) < \pi/2$ for real $t$, you have to say $\arctan(y) = x + n \pi$ for some integer $n$.  You then want to use some numerical estimates to find out which $n$ it is.

Comment: +1 for the extra work. Though, didn't you notice that you've yourself answered this question before? I guess it's not hard to forget about one answer when you have 600 of them...

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė, wish we had an automatic duplicate  checking :)

Comment: You still say  $$A+B+C=\arctan\left(\frac{\tan A+\tan B+\tan C-\tan A\tan B\tan C}{1-\tan A\tan B-\tan B\tan C-\tan C\tan A}\right)$$ which is wrong.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, I 'm afraid, things look clumsy when playing with general values?

Answer (score 73):

Once I have seen a very nice proof of this: your claim is equivalent to proving that the sum of red, green and blue angles is $\pi$. Note that in the second picture, the blue-green triangle is right and isosceles (that is 45-45-90 triangle and thus similar to small red-black triangle in the first diagram).

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: How does one know that the red angle in the second diagram is the same as the red angle in the first?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki "Note that on the second picture, the blue-green triangle is right and isosceles." The red-black triangle in the first diagram is also right and isosceles. Using different words, both angles are between a side and a diagonal of a square -- in the first diagram it is a black square and red diagonal, in the second it is a green square (out of four green segments only two are drawn) and blue diagonal.

Comment: Ahh, I see - I hadn't parsed that as the green-green-blue triangle being similar to the triangle the red arc describes in the top picture.  Maybe a small note about how both are 45-45-90 and thus similar? That's a bit more quickly-parsed at least for me than 'right and isosceles'...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Should be more explicit now ;-)

Comment: It is indeed, and excellent!  A well-earned +1.

Comment: http://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/20005.2.shtml

Comment: @HansLundmark I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: Nothing deep, just a link to a site with (more or less) the same figure plus some references to the literature.

Answer (score 42):

Consider $(1+i)$, $(1+2i)$ and $(1+3i)$ which have respective arguments of $\arctan 1$, $\arctan 2$ and $\arctan 3$.  Their product equals the sum of the arguments.  Thus

$$\arctan 1+\arctan 2+\arctan 3 = \operatorname {Arg} ((1+i)(1+2i)(1+3i)) = \operatorname {Arg} (-10) = \pi$$

Comment: ... and pretty!