# Trigonometric rectangle

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

In the rectangle ABCD,
$$1. \, BE = EF = FC = AB$$
$$2. \, \angle AEB = \beta , \angle AFB = \alpha , \angle ACB = \theta. $$
Prove that $\alpha + \theta = \beta$.

I have so far obtained that - $$1. \cos\beta =  \sin \beta$$ $$2.\cos\alpha = 2\sin\alpha$$ $$3. \cos \theta = 3\sin \theta$$
But I am not able to understand what to do next. Please help.

Comment: Your first conclusion -- that $\cos \beta = \sin \beta$ -- appears to be wrong. Can you show us the details? For it to be true, you'd need $BE = AB$, but that's not given.

Comment: oh sorry i just forgot to mention that!

Comment: You are trying to prove $\alpha+\theta=\beta$. But clearly, $\alpha>\beta>\theta$, so how can the statement be true?

Comment: @DavidH How did u get that $\alpha> \beta > \theta?$ Kindly please explain

Comment: @DavidH it is $\beta>\alpha>\theta$

Comment: @DavidH yeah I agree with ajotatxe.That was what i had been thinking...

Comment: In fact you need to prove that $\arctan 1 = \arctan \dfrac{1}{2}+\arctan \dfrac{1}{3}$. It is nice identity, used by Euler to build series for $\pi$ approximation (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersMachin-LikeFormula.html).

Comment: @ajotatxe Oops, you are right. I had alpha and beta reversed.

Comment: See nice visual proof of related problem here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272208/proving-arctan1-arctan2-arctan3-pi/272250#272250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that the three angles are acute. Moreover,

$$\tan\beta=2\tan\alpha=3\tan\theta$$

$$\begin{align}
\tan(\alpha+\theta)&=\frac{\tan\alpha+\tan\theta}{1-\tan\alpha\tan\theta}\\
&=\frac{\frac56\tan\beta}{1-\frac{\tan^2\beta}6}\\
&=\frac{5\tan\beta}{6-\tan^2\beta}
\end{align}$$

So the statement is true only if $6-\tan^2\beta=5$, that is, only if $\tan\beta=1$ or $\beta=45^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $\beta= 45degree$ because an isoceles right triangle ABE.
then $\tan(\alpha + \theta)$=$(\tan\alpha+\tan\theta)$,$1-\tan\alpha\tan\theta
=$(5/6 $\tan\beta$)$1-\tan^2\beta$=$5\tan\beta$ $6-\tan^2\beta$
gives $\tan(\alpha + \theta)=1=\tan\beta$
 $\alpha + \theta = \beta$