# Correct my proof that: $\tan^{-1}(1) + \tan^{-1}(2) +\tan^{-1}(3) = \pi$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

LHS =  $\tan^{-1}(1) + \tan^{-1}(2) + \tan^{-1}(3) $

= $\frac{\pi}{4}+ \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2+3}{1-2.3}\right)$

= $\frac{\pi}{4}+\tan^{-1}{5\over-5}$

= $\frac{\pi}{4}+ \tan^{-1}(-1)$

=$\frac{\pi}{4}-\tan^{-1}(1)$

=$\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{4}$

= 0

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: The equation $y=\tan x$ doesn't have a single solution in $x$...

Answer (score 5):

Note that we have that $$\arctan x +\arctan y =\arctan \frac{x+y}{1-xy} \pmod {\pi}$$
The $\mod \pi$ appears because the tangent function has a period of $\pi$. So it is not necessarily guranteed that $$\arctan x +\arctan y =\arctan \frac{x+y}{1-xy}$$
This is especially true since $\arctan 2$ and $\arctan 3$ are both positive, but $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ is negative in your case. So we should actually have $\arctan 2 +\arctan 3=\frac{3 \pi}{4}$.

Note that $\arctan x=\tan^{-1} x$. I add this so as to avoid confusion in notation.

Comment: "The $\mod \pi$ appears because the tangent function has a period of $\pi$" What is meant by 'function has a period of $\pi$' and $\mod \pi$?

Comment: @mikealise A function has a period in $\pi$ means that the function satisfies $$f(x+\pi)=f(x)$$ Also $x=y \pmod {\pi}$ if $x-y$ is a integer times $\pi$. So, for example $$\pi+1 =1 \pmod {\pi}$$

Comment: @mikealise Do you understand?

Answer (score 2):

Not actually showing what you did wrong. S.C.B. did that. Just a nice graphical proof of your identity.

[image: arctan 1, arctan 2, arctan 3]

Comment: The graphical proof that can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/272250/305862) is a little simpler.

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan(\arctan1+\arctan2+\arctan3)=\frac{1+\tan(\arctan2+\arctan3)}{1-\tan(\arctan2+\arctan3)}=\frac{1+\dfrac{2+3}{1-2\cdot3}}{1-\dfrac{2+3}{1-2\cdot3}}=\frac{1-1}{1+1}=0.$$

This implies

$$\arctan1+\arctan2+\arctan3=k\pi$$ for some $k$.

---

As the arc tangents are in range $(0,\pi/2)$, we have

$$0<k\pi<\frac{3\pi}{2}$$ which is conclusive.