# How to find $ \alpha + \beta $ here

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, congruences-geometry, geometric-transformation

In the below figure, ABGH, BCFG, CDEF are squares with same length. I need to find $ \alpha + \beta $

[image: Figure]

I spend an hour with this and found that answer is 90°  but according to answer key, it's 45°. Please help.

Comment: See [this numberphile video](https://youtu.be/m5evLoL0xwg) for a proof.

Comment: See the colourful proof without words here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272208/proving-arctan1-arctan2-arctan3-pi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is:
$$\tan(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{\frac13+\frac12}{1-\frac16}=1 \Rightarrow \alpha+\beta=45^0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Reflect $E$ and $H$ across line $AD$, you get new points $E',H'$.

Then $\angle AE'H' = \alpha$ since $\triangle AH'E' \cong \triangle AHE$

and

$\angle FE'E =\beta$ and $FE = FA$ since $\triangle FE'E \cong \triangle AFH$.

Since $\angle E'FE = 90^{\circ}-\beta$ we have $\angle AFE' = 90^{\circ}$.

So $\angle AE'F = (\angle FAE') = 45^{\circ}$.

Finally $\alpha +\beta = \angle H'E'E - \angle AE'F = 90^{\circ}- 45^{\circ} = 45^{\circ}$.

Comment: Please provide more info, if possible, show diagram

Comment: @RaviPrakash This is sufficient an answer for you to go away *and think for yourself* - remember this is **NOT** a homework site.