# trigonometric equation for tan^(-1)

Tags: trigonometry

Need to solve this equation:
$$\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{3} +\tan^{-1}x=  \tan^{-1}2.$$
Method with explanation is highly appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Apply tangent to both sides and use sum of angles identity for this function:

$$\arctan\frac x3+\arctan x=\arctan2\implies \tan\left(\arctan\frac x3+\arctan x\right)=\tan\arctan 2=2\implies$$

$$\implies\frac{\frac x3+x}{1-\frac{x^2}3}=2\;\;\ldots\;\text{take it from here}\;\ldots$$

Comment: what  if $x=-3$?

Comment: What with it? I bet the OP can come up with his own conclusion as we must limit the tangent function in order to get its inverse...Or you can give it all to him as I can see you already did.

Comment: Do you mean, OP will validate each value against the given relation?

Comment: I don't know, @labbhattacharjee. Why don't you ask him?

Answer (score 0):

We need to be careful while summing the inverse trigonometric ratios.

Following [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523625/showing-arctan-frac23-frac12-arctan-frac125/523626#523626), we gave $$\tan^{-1}\frac x3 +\tan^{-1}x=\begin{cases} \arctan\frac{4x}{3-x^2} &\mbox{if } x\cdot\frac x3<1\iff x^2\le3\iff -\sqrt3\le x\le\sqrt3\\ \pi+\arctan\frac{4x}{3-x^2} & \mbox{ otherwise } \end{cases} $$

Now using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values), $\displaystyle -\frac\pi2\le \tan^{-1}2\le\frac\pi2$

More precisely, $\displaystyle 0<\tan^{-1}2<\frac\pi2$

If $\displaystyle-\sqrt3\le x\le\sqrt3, \frac{4x}{3-x^2}=2\iff x^2+2x-3=0\iff x=-3,x=1$

Clearly,$\displaystyle x\ne-3$

which is more evident from $\displaystyle\tan^{-1}(-3)+\tan^{-1}(-1)<0,$ hence $\ne\tan^{-1}2$