# Find the value of the sum

Tags: trigonometry

$$\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)+\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)$$

We were also given a hint of using the trigonometric identity of $\tan(x + y)$

**Hint**

$$\tan\left(x+y\right)\:=\:\dfrac{\tan x\:+\tan y}{1-\left(\tan x\right)\left(\tan y\right)}$$

Comment: $\color{green}{\arctan\dfrac11=\arctan\dfrac12+\arctan\dfrac13.}$

Comment: @Gunz, Have a look into http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523625/showing-arctan-frac23-frac12-arctan-frac125/523626#523626

Answer (score 2):

Let $x = \arctan \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $y = \arctan \dfrac{1}{3}$. Then, $\tan x = \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $\tan y = \dfrac{1}{3}$.

Using that formula, you can easily compute $\tan(x+y)$. Do you see how to get $x+y$ from that?

Comment: Umm not really. Cause the equation uses arctan, while the hint use just tan

Comment: Using the formula, you can get $\tan(x+y) = \text{something}$. How do you solve that equation to get $x+y$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)+\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)=u $$

Take tangents on both sides using hint given.

$$ \dfrac{1/2 +1/3}{1- {\dfrac{1} {6}}} = tan(u), $$

$$  tan(u) =1$$

$$ u = \pi/4 $$

Answer (score 0):

Yep, sum of tangents identity is the way to go. Write $x=arctan\frac{1}{2}$ and $y=arctan\frac{1}{3}$.

Then $tan(arctan\frac{1}{2}+arctan\frac{1}{3})=\frac{tan(arctan\frac{1}{2})+tan(arctan\frac{1}{3})}{1-(tan(arctan\frac{1}{2}))(tan(arctan\frac{1}{3}))}$

This is equal to $\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}}{1-(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{3})}=\frac{\frac{5}{6}}{\frac{5}{6}}=1$

Thus $tan(x+y)=1$ and $x+y=\boxed{\frac{\pi}{4}}$