# An equality with inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

I've stumbled on the equality 
$$
\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) \left(\pi -\tan ^{-1}\left(4
   \sqrt{3}\right)\right)=4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)
   \cot ^{-1}(3).
$$
Out of curiosity, is there a simple proof?  I don't see how it can be done with standard formulas like $\cot^{-1}x=\pi/2-\tan^{-1}x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

[For](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/are-mathrmarccotx-and-arctan1-x-the-same-function) $x>0,\cot^{-1}x=\tan^{-1}1/x$

Using the formula in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523625/showing-arctan-frac23-frac12-arctan-frac125)

$2\tan^{-1}(1/3)=\tan^{-1}\dfrac{2\cdot1/3}{1-(1/3)^2}=\tan^{-1}3/4$

and use the same formula for $2\tan^{-1}\dfrac2{\sqrt3}$

Observe that $\dfrac2{\sqrt3}>1$