# Solution verification for $y'$ when $y=\sin^{-1}(\frac{2x}{1+x^2})$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

I was required to find $y'$ when $y=\sin^{-1}(\frac{2x}{1+x^2})$

This is my solution.

[image]

Above when I put $\sqrt{x^4-2x+1}=\sqrt{(1-x^2)^2}$ then I get the correct answer but when I put $\sqrt{x^4-2x+1}=\sqrt{(x^2-1)^2}$ then I get something else.

Now my question is that which one is correct and why? How you will come to know that we should put $\sqrt{x^4-2x+1}=\sqrt{(1-x^2)^2}$ and not $\sqrt{x^4-2x+1}=\sqrt{(x^2-1)^2}$

Kindly help me.

Comment: Well, $(x^2-1)^2=(1-x^2)^2$, so it doesn't matter at all. To add to this:
$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-1)^2=2(x^2-1)\cdot(2x)$, and $\frac{d}{dx}(1-x^2)^2=2(1-x^2)\cdot(-2x)=2(x^2-1)\cdot(2x)=\frac{d}{dx} (x^2-1)^2$, so I assume you may have forgotten a minus sign somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

For real $a,$ $$\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$$

$=+a$ if $a\ge0$ and $=-a$ if $a<0$

Things will be clearer with the following :

Using my answer here: [showing $\arctan(\frac{2}{3}) = \frac{1}{2} \arctan(\frac{12}{5})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523625/showing-arctan-frac23-frac12-arctan-frac125) and $\arctan y=\arcsin\dfrac y{\sqrt{y^2+1}}$

$$2\arctan x=\begin{cases} \arcsin\frac{2x}{1+x^2} &\mbox{if } x^2<1\\ \pi+\arcsin\frac{2x}{1+x^2} & \mbox{if } x^2>1\end{cases} $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Given
$$
y = \sin^{-1}\left( \frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right),
$$

then
$$
\sin(y) = \frac{2x}{1+x^2},
$$

so
$$
\cos(y) y' = \left( \frac{2x}{1+x^2} \right)'.
$$

Now
$$
\cos(y) = \sqrt{ 1 - \sin^2(y) } =
\sqrt{ 1 - \left( \frac{2x}{1+x^2} \right)^2 },
$$

so you get
$$
y' = \frac{ \displaystyle \left( \frac{2x}{1+x^2} \right)' }
{ \displaystyle \sqrt{ 1 - \left( \frac{2x}{1+x^2} \right)^2 }}.
$$

And
$$
\left( \frac{2x}{1+x^2} \right)' = 2 \frac{1 - x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}.
$$

So final is
$$
y' = 2 \frac{ 1 - x^2 }{ \displaystyle (1+x^2) \sqrt{ (1+x^2)^2 - 4x^2 }}
= 2 \frac{ 1 - x^2 }{ \displaystyle (1+x^2) \sqrt{ (1-x^2)^2 }}.
$$

Thus
$$
y' =
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
|x| < 1 : \displaystyle \frac{2}{1+x^2}\\\\
|x| > 1 : \displaystyle \frac{-2}{1+x^2}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: You should add that $|y|\le \pi/2$, and therefore $\cos(y)\ge 0$.

Comment: @Mercy, yep, but I assumed that that was clear as I used the positive root...