# Finding the modulus and argument of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I would need help with this question:

$$Z = \frac{(1+j2)^2(4-j3)^3 }{ (3+j4)^4 (2-j3)}$$

My starting point for this question is to expand the complex numbers first then continue doing but after expanding I am stuck.

Am I on the right track? Kindly help :D.

Comment: Can you show us the result of your expansion

Comment: Opening the parentheses is not a good idea. Modulus and argument behave nicely when we MULTIPLY. So it is much easier to compute modulus and argument of a product then of a sum. So the general approach would be to FACTOR not to open parantheses. But your expression is already factored.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

For modulus use $\left|\dfrac{a^mb^n}{c^pd^q}\right|=\dfrac{|a|^m|b|^n}{|c|^p|d|^q}$ where $m,n,p,q$ are real

For the principal argument($\in(-\pi,\pi]$) ([definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation)),

$$A=2\arctan\dfrac21+3\arctan\dfrac{-3}4-4\arctan\dfrac43-\arctan\dfrac{-3}2$$

using [showing $\arctan(\frac{2}{3}) = \frac{1}{2} \arctan(\frac{12}{5})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523625/showing-arctan-frac23-frac12-arctan-frac125/523626#523626) and [Are $\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ and $\arctan(1/x)$ the same function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/are-mathrmarccotx-and-arctan1-x-the-same-function)

$2\arctan2=\pi+\arctan\dfrac{2\cdot2}{1-2^2}=\pi-\arctan\dfrac43$

$$\implies A=\pi-3\arctan\dfrac34-3\arctan\dfrac43+\arctan\dfrac32$$

$$=\pi-3\left(\text{arccot}\dfrac43+\arctan\dfrac43\right)+\arctan\dfrac32$$

$$=\pi-3\cdot\dfrac\pi2+\dfrac\pi2-\arctan\dfrac23$$

$$\equiv-\arctan\dfrac23\pmod{2\pi}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $-j(3+j4)=4-j3$, it reduces to
$$Z=\frac{(1+j2)^2(4-j3)^3}{(3+j4)^4(2-j3)}=\frac{(1+j2)^2}{(2-j3)(3+j4)}\cdot\left(\frac{4-j3}{3+j4}\right)^3=\frac{(1+j2)^2}{(2-j3)(3+j4)}\cdot(-j)^3$$
Expanding numerator and denominator separately gives
$$Z=\frac{-4-3j}{18-j}$$
Now multiplying it by $\frac{18+j}{18+j}$ gives
$$Z=\frac{-4-3j}{18-j}\cdot\frac{18+j}{18+j}=\frac{-4\times 18+3+(-4-3\times 18)j}{18^2+1}=\frac{-69-58j}{325}$$
I'm sure you can continue from here.

Comment: How did (4-j3/3+j4)^3 become -j^3?

Comment: @Ong: Dividing the both sides of $-j(3+j4)=4-j3$ by $3+j4$ gives $-j=\frac{4-j3}{3+j4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, after expanding the above you get something that looks like:

$$ Z =\frac{a+bj}{x+yj}$$

You can simplify this by rationalising the denominator:

$$Z= \frac{a+bj}{x+yj} \times\frac{x-yj}{x-yj} $$

This will now give you a complex number of the form: $p+qj$

Modulus(Z) $ = \sqrt{p^2 + q^2}$

$\arg(Z) = \arctan \left(\frac{q}{p}\right)$

There are some very good tricks in the other answers so you can take advantage of them.