# Find the angle of complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let
$$
z = \frac{a-jw}{a+jw}.
$$
Then the angle of $z$ is
$$
-\tan^{-1}z\left(\frac{w}{a}\right) -\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{w}{a}\right) = -2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{w}{a}\right).
$$
How is that so?

Comment: $\arg (a)$ works similar to $\log (a)$ in that $\arg (\frac{a}{b})$ = $\arg(a) - \arg(b)$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523625/showing-arctan-frac23-frac12-arctan-frac125/523626#523626  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply numerator and denomination by the conjugate of  ***a+jw***  i.e.  ***a-jw***
So the numerator becomes  ***a<sup>2</sup> -w<sup>2</sup> - 2awj*** and the denominator will be real and you'll be able to solve it and get the final argument.

OR

Taking numerator as z<sub>1</sub> and denominator as z<sub>2</sub> 
We know  **z<sub>1</sub>=|z<sub>1</sub>|e<sup>iarg(z<sub>1</sub>)</sup>**

Similarly **z<sub>2</sub>=|z<sub>2</sub>|e<sup>iarg(z<sub>1</sub>)</sup>**

Dividing we have, **z=(|z<sub>1</sub>|/|z<sub>2</sub>|)e<sup>i(arg(z<sub>1</sub>)-arg(z<sub>2</sub>))</sup>**

=>***arg(z)= arg(z<sub>1</sub>)-arg(z<sub>2</sub>)*** 
Also, arg of a complex number is tan<sup>-1</sup>(complex part/real part) which in case of numerator will be **tan<sup>-1</sup>(-w/a) = -tan<sup>-1</sup>(w/a)**

and for denominator , argument will be **tan<sup>-1</sup>(w/a)**
and since we are dividing than be another complex number which is denominator, we subtract their arguments to get the final argument.

Answer (score 6):

They are conjugate complex numbers

$$ \dfrac{r \cdot e ^{-i \theta }}{{r \cdot e ^{i \theta }}{} } =e ^{- 2 i \theta } $$

Comment: Simple and nice. +1

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that it could be easier to see writing $$z = \frac{a-jw}{a+jw}= \frac{a-jw}{a+jw} \times \frac{a-jw}{a-jw}=\frac{(a-jw)^2}{a^2+w^2}=\frac{a^2-w^2}{a^2+w^2}-\frac{2  a w}{a^2+w^2}j$$ which makes the angle to be such that $$\tan(\theta)=-\frac{2aw}{a^2-w^2}=-\frac{2\frac aw}{1-(\frac aw)^2}$$ and to remember the development of $\tan(2x)$.

Comment: I have a small question please, I read on a copybook about complex numbers, a sentence that said "if $z$ is a real number then $$arg z= 0, \pi$$ deprived of the denominator". And a similar one "if $z$ is pure immaginary then $$arg z= \pm \pi/2$$, deprived of the numerator and denominator". Any idea what could this possibly mean? Thanks in advance ... By the way I am just asking about the sentence "deprived of ..."

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a,w\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\arg\left(\frac{a-wi}{a+wi}\right)=$$
$$\arg\left(\frac{a-wi}{a+wi}\cdot\frac{a-wi}{a-wi}\right)=$$
$$\arg\left(\frac{(a-wi)^2}{a^2+w^2}\right)=$$
$$\arg\left(\frac{a^2-w^2-2awi}{a^2+w^2}\right)=$$
$$\arg\left(a^2-w^2-2awi\right)-\arg\left(a^2+w^2\right)=$$
$$\arg\left(a^2-w^2-2awi\right)-0=$$
$$\arg\left(a^2-w^2-2awi\right)=$$
$$\arg\left(a^2-w^2-2awi\right)=$$
$$\arg\left((a-wi)^2\right)=$$
$$\arg\left((a-wi)(a-wi)\right)=$$
$$\arg\left(a-wi\right)+\arg\left(a-wi\right)=$$
$$2\arg\left(a-wi\right)=$$
$$-2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{w}{a}\right)$$