# Trigonometric Identity Similar to Tangent Addition Identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I found the following trigonometric relationship in a paper and I can't seem to derive it.

$1/2 arctan(\frac{2\sqrt{l}}{l-1}) = arctan(\sqrt{l})$

Where $l$ is a natural number.  It seems similar to the tangent addition identity, but I can't use this identity to make a connection between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Like my answer here: [showing $\arctan(\frac{2}{3}) = \frac{1}{2} \arctan(\frac{12}{5})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523625/showing-arctan-frac23-frac12-arctan-frac125),

$$2\arctan\sqrt l=\arctan\dfrac{2\sqrt l}{1-l}\text{ if }\sqrt l<1$$

Comment: \sqrt{l}<1 doesn't hold for my problem.

Comment: @billbob, Why & where it is specified?

Comment: In the question.  I say $l$ is a natural, but make no mention of the assumption you make, so you should assume that it doesn't hold.

Comment: @billbob, Can be $l=0?$  Then we have three cases $l=0,1,>1$

Comment: @billbob, "Regrettably, there seems to be no general agreement about whether to include 0 in the set of natural numbers." : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNumber.html

Comment: Right, $l \ge 1$