# How to solve $2\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x-x^2}=\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}(1-x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$2\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x-x^2}=\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}(1-x)$$
I wasn't sure on how to go from here because I tried to draw triangles for each tangent function but that didnt work and I know that I can't distribute via doing tangent on both sides.

(though I do enjoy complex methods in solving this, I do appreciate a high school level process of doing this problem.)

Comment: Have you tried with Newton-Ralphson method?

Comment: HINT. 2arctan(f(x)g(x))-arctan(f(x))-arctan(g(x))=0 usually has a root where f(x)=g(x)..... try with f(x)=x, g(x)=1-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting $u = 1-x,v=x,$ you need to solve $2\arctan \sqrt{uv} = \arctan u + \arctan v.$

Taking tangents on both sides and applying tangent addition and double angle formulae gives $\frac{2\sqrt{uv}}{1-uv}=\frac{u+v}{1-uv}\implies 2\sqrt{uv}=u+v\implies 2\sqrt{x-x^2}=1\implies 4(x-x^2)=1$ which is a simple quadratic to solve.

Answer (score 2):

*I assume you want to prove equality between both sides. I show that your equality is almost correct but off by a constant of $\pi/4$*

This is easy enough with calculus. If we differentiate either side we get
$$\frac{2 - 4 x}{x^4 - 2 x^3 + x^2 + 1}$$
and thus our functions differ by at most a constant. Setting $x=0$ we find
$$2\arctan\sqrt{x-x^2}\bigg|_{x=0}=2\arctan(0)=0\\ [\arctan(x)+\arctan(1-x)]\bigg|_{x=0}=\arctan(0)+\arctan(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
We thus find that we must add $\pi/4$ to the LHS of your equality to have both sides be equal

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

We need $x-x^2\ge0\iff 0\le x\le1$

Again, $x-x^2=\dfrac{1-(2x-1)^2}4\le\dfrac14$

$\implies0\le x-x^2\le\dfrac14$

Now use my answer  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523625/showing-arctan-frac23-frac12-arctan-frac125) to find $x=\dfrac12$