# Why expansion of this term gives negative value?

Tags: trigonometry

During helping a junior , I came to this term:
$$
\sin\left(4\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$

using calculator , you will find the value $\frac{24}{25}$ which is correct one. But when you expand it like this(which my junior did) :
\begin{align}
\sin\left(4\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2}\right) &= \\
&= \sin\left(2\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}\right)    &  [2\tan^{-1}x = \tan^{-1}\frac{2x}{1-x^2}] \\
&=\sin\left(2\tan^{-1}\frac{4}{3}\right) \\
&=\sin\left(\tan^{-1}\frac{2\cdot\frac{4}{3}}{1-\frac{16}{9}}\right) \\
&=\sin\left(\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac{24}{7}\right)\right)
\end{align}

which value is $-\frac{24}{25}$ . Why this expansion is giving wrong answer ? where is the error ?

Comment: See my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523625/showing-arctan-frac23-frac12-arctan-frac125

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity $$\tan 2\theta = \frac{2 \tan \theta}{1 - \tan^2\theta}$$ is always true, but it does *not* always imply that $$2 \arctan x = \arctan \frac{2x}{1-x^2}.$$ The problem is that multiple values of $\theta$ have the same value of $\tan \theta$, and by convention $\arctan x$ chooses the angle $\theta$ between $-\frac\pi2$ and $\frac\pi2$.

In your case, $2 \arctan \frac43 \approx 1.85$, which is bigger than $\frac\pi2$, and $\arctan -\frac{24}{7} \approx -1.29$: it is $2 \arctan \frac43 - \pi$. When you take the sine of both values, since $\sin (x + \pi) = - \sin x$, you will be off by a minus sign.

To deal with this, you can observe that if $x > 1$, then $\arctan x > \frac\pi4$, so $2 \arctan x > \frac\pi2$ and you'll get an answer off by $\pi$ when that happens. This tells you when to subtract a $\pi$ when working with this identity.

Answer (score 0):

It should be $$\sin { \left( 4\tan ^{ -1 }{ \left( \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  }  \right)  } =\\ \tan ^{ -1 }{ \left( \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  } =t\\ \tan { t=\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  } \Rightarrow \sin { t } =\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 5 }  } ,\cos { t } =\frac { 2 }{ \sqrt { 5 }  } \\ \sin { \left( 4t \right)  } =2\sin { 2t\cos { 2t }  } =4\sin { t\cos { t } \left( \cos ^{ 2 }{ t } -\sin ^{ 2 }{ t }  \right)  } =4\cdot \frac { 2 }{ \sqrt { 5 }  } \cdot \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 5 }  } \left( \frac { 4 }{ 5 } -\frac { 1 }{ 5 }  \right) =\frac { 24 }{ 25 } $$

Comment: If you follow this procedure , you can get the answer. But my question is not how can I get proper answer. I wanna know in my procedure , what is my mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

When bigger angles are calculated we should check in which quadrant the angle lies after rotation.The tan in second quadrant is negative.So we need to change sign of
$$ \tan^{-1}\dfrac{2 \dfrac{4}{3}}{1-\dfrac{16}{9}}  $$

Else all OK.

Comment: We don't *change the sign* of $\arctan$: we subtract $\pi$. (In this case, because we're taking $\sin$ afterwards, the two are equivalent, but if we were to apply $\cos$ on the outside instead, changing the sign would give you the wrong answer.)

Comment: It was a typo, corrected. Since tan in second quadrant is < 0, and we are having a definite angle etc.... anyway