# Given that $0<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0<\beta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and that...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

**Problem:** Given that $0<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2}$, $0<\beta<\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\tan{\alpha=2}$ and that $\tan{\beta=3},$ find $\alpha + \beta.$

**Attempt:** Given the restrictions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$, it follows that $0<\alpha+\beta<\pi.$ So depending on if $\alpha+\beta \ $ is in the first or second quadrant, $\tan{(a+b)}$ can be either positive or negtive. Using the addition formula for tangent I get

$$\tan{(a+b)}=\frac{\tan{\alpha}+\tan{\beta}}{1-\tan{\alpha}\tan{\beta}}=\frac{2+3}{1-2\cdot 3}=\frac{5}{-5}=-1.$$

This tells me that $\pi/2 < \alpha + \beta < \pi.$ So,

$$\alpha+\beta=\arctan{(-1)}+\pi k=-\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi k \ , \ \ k\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

$n=1$ takes me to the desired quadrant: $$\alpha + \beta =-\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi=\frac{3\pi}{4}.$$

**Question:** If $\tan{\beta}=-1/3,$ would the answer then have been $$\alpha + \beta= \frac{\pi}{4} \ \ ?$$

Comment: If $\tan \beta = -\frac13$ and $-\frac{\pi}2<\beta<0$ then $\alpha + \beta =\frac{\pi}4.$

Comment: See my answer here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523625/showing-arctan-frac23-frac12-arctan-frac125