# Inverse Trigonometry System of Equations

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

$$2\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{x-x^2}\right) = \tan^{-1}\left(x\right)\: +\, \tan^{-1}\left(1-x\right)$$

I have a feeling solution includes drawing triangles but cannot make the leap to get the solution

Comment: What are you trying to do? Solve that equation for $x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take tangent of both sides (apply double angle and sum of angle formula and remember that $\tan(\tan^{-1}y) = y$):

$$\frac{2\sqrt{x-x^2}}{1 - (x-x^2)} = \frac{x+1-x}{1-x(1-x)}$$

and solve that equation.

Comment: How did you get the above equation? Could you elaborate what you did after simply taking the tangent?

Comment: @JeffreyChiu : He used the double-angle formula and the sum of angles formula for tangent.

Comment: @JeffreyChiu Does my edit help?

Comment: Yes I see now, thanks a lot

Comment: @Deepak, Taking tan can be erroneous, right as $\tan(m\pi+u)=\tan u$ for integer $m$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Would taking $\frac{2\sqrt{x-x^2}}{1 - (x-x^2)} = \frac{x+1-x}{1-x(1-x)} + k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ fix this issue?

Comment: @Deepak, It can not be arbitrary $k$. Please check one of the links in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

We need $x(1-x)\ge0\iff x(x-1)\le0\iff0\le x\le1$

$\implies\dfrac{x+1-x}2\ge\sqrt{x(1-x)}$

Now use $$\arctan x+\arctan y= \arctan\frac{x+y}{1-xy}$$ if $xy<1$

See [Inverse trigonometric function identity doubt: $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y =-\pi+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$, when $x<0$, $y<0$, and $xy>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan)

OR  [showing $\arctan(\frac{2}{3}) = \frac{1}{2} \arctan(\frac{12}{5})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523625/showing-arctan-frac23-frac12-arctan-frac125)