# calculating $\tan^{-1}(a)+\tan^{-1}(b)$

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors

I am trying to calculate the sum of the angles between the position vectors of two imaginary numbers and the real axis without using the $\operatorname{arg} function.

The numbers are:

$4+i$ and $5+3i$

According to Wolfarm the angles $\tan^{-1}(\frac14)+\tan^{-1}(\frac35)$ are equal to $\tan^{-1}(1)$

My teacher told me that there is a way to multiply vectors in $2D$ space to get the sum of their angle as an expression of $\arctan$ ...

Comment: $\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x\tan y}$, so
$\tan(\tan^{-1}a+\tan^{-1}b)=\frac{a+b}{1-ab}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523625/showing-arctan-frac23-frac12-arctan-frac125

Comment: Note that $\arg(a+bi)=\textrm{atan2}(b,a)=\tan^{-1}(b/a)$.

Comment: See [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html)

Comment: see here https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-sum-of-two-inverse-tangents

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown that is incorrect it should be arctan that but i do not know why