# Express $x$ in terms of $a$ and $b$: $\sin^{-1} {\frac{2a}{1+a^2}} + \sin^{-1}{\frac{2b}{1+b^2}} = 2\tan^{-1}x$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the value of $x$ from the following equation in terms of $a$ and $b$
>   $$\sin^{-1} {2a\over{1+a^2}} + \sin^{-1}{2b\over{1+b^2}} = 2\tan^{-1}x$$

I tried to expand the LHS using the formula $$\sin^{-1}c+\sin^{-1}d = \sin^{-1}\left(c\sqrt{1+d^2} + d\sqrt{1+c^2}\right)$$

But it didn't work out. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: I think you left out the parentheses on the right-hand side of the last formula.  Please check that you agree with my edit.

Comment: @saulspatz Oh yes. Thanks mate

Answer (score 3):

Divide both sides by $2$, then using the $\arctan(x)=y \implies x=\tan(y)$ you will get that $$x=\tan\left(\frac{\arcsin\left(\frac{2a}{1+a^2}\right)+\arcsin\left(\frac{2b}{1+b^2}\right)}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your formatting will look a lot nicer if you use `\arctan` and `\tan` instead of `tan` and `arctan`.

Comment: @saulspatz thank you!

Comment: My pleasure.  I also suggest that you put all mathematical expressions, including numbers, inside dollars signs.  `$2$` comes out as $2$.

Comment: Welcome! Another typesetting hint: use `\left( ... \right)` instead of just `( ... )` for parentheses that need to contain large expressions; they will grow as needed.

Comment: Now I'm one of you guys hahaha, thank you again for the great suggestions!

Comment: Wlecome to MSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) will help you typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\arctan a=u,a=\tan u$

If $-\dfrac\pi2\le2u\le\dfrac\pi2\iff -1\le a\le1$ $$P=\arcsin\dfrac{2a}{1+a^2}=2\arctan a$$

If $2u>\dfrac\pi2,P=\pi-2\arctan a$

If $2u<-\dfrac\pi2,P=-\pi-2\arctan a$

Now use my answer in [showing $\arctan(\frac{2}{3}) = \frac{1}{2} \arctan(\frac{12}{5})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523625/showing-arctan-frac23-frac12-arctan-frac125)