# Sum of angles in a $3 \times 3$ grid

Tags: geometry

I know this is easy to lots of you but I am just struggling to find the solution.  How can I prove the sum of the highlighted angles in the following 3 times 3 square grid is equal to $\pi$?

[image: Picture]

Comment: Answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/197393/26306) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/272208/26306).

Comment: Cool, feel free to mark as duplicated. Thanks!

Comment: This is a question from Brilliant. Brilliant problems cannot be discussed or solved anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
Here's a fun little proof without words. Sorry for the horrible art skills.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Apply the arctan addition formula to angles $\arctan(1), \arctan(2), \arctan(3)$.

Answer (score 0):

The first angle is $\pi /4$ because his tangent is equal to $1$ so we must show that $a+b=3\pi /4$. Looking to the picture we have $\tan a= 2$ and $\tan b= 3$ so:

$$\tan(a+b)=\frac{\tan a + \tan b}{1-\tan a \tan b}=\frac{2+3}{1-2\cdot3}=-1$$

and once $a+b \le \pi$ then $a+b=3\pi /4$.