# $\arctan(2\sqrt2)+2\arctan(\sqrt2)=\pi$

Tags: trigonometry

How this equality is verified.

$$\arctan(2\sqrt2)+2\arctan(\sqrt2)=\pi$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $$\tan(A+B+C)=\dfrac{\tan A+\tan B+\tan C-\tan A\tan B\tan C}{\cdots}$$

$$\tan(\arctan(2\sqrt2)+2\arctan(\sqrt2))=\dfrac{2\sqrt2+\sqrt2+\sqrt2-2\sqrt2(\sqrt2)^2}{\cdots}=0$$

$$\implies\arctan(2\sqrt2)+2\arctan(\sqrt2)$$ must be multiple of $\pi$

Again,  as $2\sqrt2,\sqrt2>0$

$$\dfrac\pi2>\arctan(2\sqrt2)>\arctan(\sqrt2)>0$$

$$\implies0<\arctan(2\sqrt2)+2\arctan(\sqrt2)<3\cdot\dfrac\pi2$$

Now what is the multiple of $\pi$ that lies $\in\left(0,3\cdot\dfrac\pi2\right)$

**See also**: [Why does $\tan^{-1}(1)+\tan^{-1}(2)+\tan^{-1}(3)=\pi$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197393/why-does-tan-11-tan-12-tan-13-pi/197397#197397)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Inverse trigonometric function identity doubt: $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y =-\pi+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$, when $x<0$, $y<0$, and $xy>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan)

$$2\arctan\sqrt2=\pi+\arctan\dfrac{2\sqrt2}{1-(\sqrt2)^2}=?$$

Now $\arctan(-x)=-\arctan x$

Answer (score 2):

We can use the [sum identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) for the tangent function

$$\tan(x\pm y)=\frac{\tan x\pm \tan y}{1\mp \tan x \tan y}$$

to check the given identity by

$$\arctan(2\sqrt2)+2\arctan(\sqrt2)=\pi$$

$$\iff \arctan(2\sqrt2)+\arctan(\sqrt2)=\pi-\arctan(\sqrt2)$$

that is

$$\frac{2\sqrt 2+\sqrt 2}{1-2\sqrt 2 \cdot \sqrt 2}\stackrel{\text{?}}=\frac{0-\sqrt 2}{1+0}$$